# Identify strength and location of change in sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

Suppose I have table of where rows contain measurements of objects ("A","B","C","D") over time (t1 to t5).

```
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,0,3,0,0,3,0,0,0,
                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                     nrow = c(4,5), byrow=TRUE))
colnames(mat) <- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5")
rownames(mat) <- c("A","B","C","D"); mat
```

Table looks like this:

```
  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
A  0  0  0  3  0
B  0  3  0  0  0
C  1  0  0  0  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
```

**How can I generate two new columns** - one containing **max value**, and second containing **name of column with that value**?

I should look like this:

```
  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5  strength  time
A  0  0  0  3  0         3    t4
B  0  3  0  0  0         3    t2
C  1  0  0  0  0         1    t1
D  0  0  0  0  1         1    t5
```

I hope this is sufficient reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- max.col(mat) 
cbind(mat, strength=mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat), indx)],
                  time=names(mat)[indx])

#   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 strength time
#A  0  0  0  3  0        3   t4
#B  0  3  0  0  0        3   t2
#C  1  0  0  0  0        1   t1
#D  0  0  0  0  1        1   t5
```